# Modifying some rewrite rules

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have the following rewrite rules:

```
RewriteRule ^section/(.*)/(.*)_(.*).html$ index.php?section_permalink=$1&content_permalink=$2&content_id=$3 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^section/(.*)/page_(.*)/$ index.php?section_permalink=$1&page=$2 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^section/(.*)/$ index.php?section_permalink=$1 [QSA,L]
```

I would like to modify them in order to get rid of the /section/.

How can I do this?

Thank you!

Comment: What do you mean by "get rid of the /section/"? You want it out of the rules? You want it out of the browser's URL address bar?

Comment: I want to remove it from the rules and of course from the browser's URL address bar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)_(.*).html$ index.php?section_permalink=$1&content_permalink=$2&content_id=$3 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/page_(.*)/$ index.php?section_permalink=$1&page=$2 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ index.php?section_permalink=$1 [QSA,L]
```